# Determine the equation of the plane that goes through 2 given points, and which forms a given angle with another plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I hope someone can help me with this one too.

Determine the equation of the plane which goes through the points $M(0,2,0)$ and $N(2,0,0)$, and which forms an angle of $\pi/3$ with the plane $x=0$.

Comment: Someone can help you if they know what you did.

Comment: Thing is I'm absolutely stuck, so I have no starting point. Couldn't find something understandable neither on the internet or in my book, so I'm kinda relying on someone to guide me step by step considering they have the time and will to do so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint 1**: start withvthe equation of the plane in the form $$ax+by+cz=d$$

Since $M$ and $N$ lie on the plane, you can obtain the equation of the plane with just one unknown coefficient.

**Hint 2**: the planes are at angle $\frac{\pi}{3}$ means their normals are also, so you can use dot product to determine the values of this unknown coefficient.